# How to load ag-grid-react from a CDN

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Trying like this (full HTML file contents):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@19.0.0/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-react@19.0.0/umd/ag-grid-react.min.js"></script>
```

But ag-grid-react doesn't load:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ColDefUtil' of undefined
```

`ag-grid-community.min.js` has created `window.agGrid` and there is `ColDefUtil` there, but `ag-grid-react` fails to find it.

Please advise.

Comment: can you show us the html file where you are adding these scripts? is this a React app?

Comment: this is full HTML file contents - minimal example demonstrating the loading issue

Answer (score 0):

I ended up dynamically loading (heavy) `ag-grid` from a CDN and compiling (light) `ag-grid-react` into one of app chunks and wiring them together via `webpack externals`.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but did you have an example?